# How to create Header over Header

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table:

```
id   |  BL         | ML            |BL         | ML
---------------------------------------------------------
1    | Field01     |Name           | Field34   | Field36   
2    | Field02     |Age            | Field35   | Field37
```

Required result:

```
Id   |            Open             |    Closed
---------------------------------------------------------
     |  BL         | ML            |BL         | ML
---------------------------------------------------------
1    | Field01     |Name           | Field34   | Field36   
2    | Field02     |Age            | Field35   | Field37
```

Comment: The column names in your reference table do not have unique names.

Comment: Please add more details and what it is you've tried.  Where is it that you are expecting to see this output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in just SQL Server.  You should be handling this type of display within your presentation tool.

Answer (score 0):

It seems weird to do this kind of thing in SQL Server.  I don't think you can even do this in SQL Server.  If you have access to Python, you can use Python to do this kind of thing, which is called a MultiIndex.  This may be going off on a tangent, but you can refer to the link below as to how to create a MultiIndex.

https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.05-hierarchical-indexing.html

[image]